# How to extract year from a date and compare it with current year in order to select records with date equal to current year?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I would like to extract year from a date in ArcMap definition query and compare it to current year in order to select only records with same year as current year.

The problem I am facing is that the SQL query needs to have "date" string in definition query.
Following query works fine when "date" string is included in the query
CREATE_DATE between date '2023-01-01 00:00:01' AND date '2023-12-31 23:59:59'

I have tried different methods like `CONVERT, DATEPART, EXTRACT` but none of them worked.
Here are some of the methods I tried.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [CREATE_DATE],120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEADD(Year, 0, GETDATE()),112))

EXTRACT(Year FROM "CREATE_DATE") = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEADD(Year, 0, GETDATE()),112)

Left("CREATE_DATE",4) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEADD(Year, 0, GETDATE()),112)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it myself.

The solution is EXTRACT(YEAR from "CREATE_DATE") = EXTRACT(YEAR from CURRENT_DATE) .